# Inject SQL script in shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, sqlplus

In my docker container i am trying to -

1. Stop a db while in sqlplus
2. Run a command under a specific directory
3. Start back the db

Below is the sample script i was trying but that gives me errors like command not found .
Please help me on this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(sqlplus -L sys/$TIA_SYS_PWD@tia as sysdba <<< "select * from v\$option where PARAMETER = 'Unified Auditing';" | grep FALSE) == *FALSE* ]]; then
     sqlplus -L -S  / as sysdba <<< "shutdown immediate"
     cd $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib; make -f ins_rdbms.mk uniaud_on ioracle
     sqlplus -L -S / as sysdba <<< "startup"
     sqlplus -L sys/$TIA_SYS_PWD@tia as sysdba <<< "select * from v\$option where PARAMETER = 'Unified Auditing';"
else
     echo "Unified Auditing already enabled"   
fi
```

Error message is attached [image]

Comment: Which command was not found? BTW, instead of catching the stdout of `grep`, you better use `grep -q FALSE` and evaluate the _grep_ exit code.

Comment: It was saying like - ./test.sh: line 6:  : command not found

Comment: And what is the content of this line? You didn't even tell us that the script you posted is named `test.sh`? How on earth should one help you, if you witholt  even the most elementary information. You know the filename and you know the line inside the file. Wouldn't it natural to post this information together with the error message?

Comment: Line 5, 6 , 7 & 8 are the lines after if statement . And it should be known that its a shell script so whatever xyz.sh file it would be anyways , yes missed the error message but have edited it now .

Comment: The screenshot indeed is helpful. Since the error message does not say, what command is not found - usually you would see a message like _line 5: **xxxx**: command not found_ - I suspect that you have some non-printable characters in your script, for instance a character which displays as white space, but is different from 0x20. I suggest that you run your script by `./test.sh 2>&1 >out.txt` and then inspect `out.txt` using a hex editor. Or you check `test.sh` for strange hex codes in front of the commands.

Comment: The whitespaces which was present after if statement is what was causing the issue , the script works fine otherwise . Thanks for the headsup on this . Appreciate

Comment: Can you try "which sqlplus" from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best way to talk to your database from a bash script is using a HERE document

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

For example

```
sqlplus ... <<EOF
   whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
   [QUERY]
   exit;
EOF

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   # [QUERY] returned an error
fi
```

You will need command line arguments and 'set' calls within the heredoc to fit your particular use case but the *whenever sqlerror* clause is useful to check a return code from your sql statement in the script.

This works for not just sqlplus plus lots of other kinds of database engines as well.

Comment: Thanks i understand but i am new to shell and sql as well , i tried whatever i could but couldn't phrase the correct format , if you can help me with that it would be great

Comment: @OM-ॐ - ah I see your comments above, to me it seems sqlplus isn't in your path.

Comment: I figured it out Bret , it was because of whitespaces , thanks for the info anyways